# Error in handleMessage: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-tools

i am using 'kotlinx-serialization-runtime-js' in my firebase functions project. Everything so far went as expected. But since i am using:

```
val js = kotlinx.serialization.json.Json(JsonConfiguration.Stable)
             .kotlinx.serialization.stringify(result)
```

i can't run it local in the functions emulator. When starting it shows in the log:

```
Error in handleMessage: {"frb":{"cwd":"/home/drindt/.../functions","projectId":"c*******r-d*********t","triggerId":"","emulators":{},"socketPath":"/tmp/fire_emu_144610.sock"},"opts":{"nodeBinary":"/usr/bin/node","env":{"GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS":"/home/drindt/.config/firebase/credentials.json"}}} => RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at extractTriggers (/home/drindt/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/extractTriggers.js:2:32)
```

The recursive invocation of *extractTriggers* lead to the problem. I found in another file the note that when this error happen it's because other modules are exported than just function modules. I look into the kotlin compiled js files confirm that. If i remove the *stringify* from above everything works.
It would be very nice if i could have some assistance to solve this problem. Thank you for taking your time to read and help me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same issue here, and since I'm not able to comment yet (not enough reputation), I'm posting my issue and it's solution here:

In short, the lesson for me was

> Don't use `export const` in your `index.ts` for anything other than functions.

So for me it was showing the following error:

```
functions: Maximum call stack size exceeded
function was killed because it raised an unhandled error.
```

When I looked around in the `firebase-debug.log` file, I found that the error originated from `extractTriggers.js` which was located at:

```
/Users/$name$/.cache/firebase/tools/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/extractTriggers.js
```

But I still could not figure out what was the root cause, so I used `console.log` to print out the function names that were being called in `extractTriggers.js`:

```
i  firestore: Firestore Emulator logging to firestore-debug.log
i  ui: Emulator UI logging to ui-debug.log
i  functions: Watching "/Users/****/Desktop/.../firebase-cloud-functions/functions" for Cloud Functions...
>  ExtractTriggers for function options
>  ExtractTriggers for function allowedHeaders
>  ExtractTriggers for function 0
>  ExtractTriggers for function 1
>  ExtractTriggers for function 2
>  ExtractTriggers for function credentials
>  ExtractTriggers for function methods
>  ExtractTriggers for function origin
>  ExtractTriggers for function preflightContinue
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebaseAdmin
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
>  ExtractTriggers for function Promise
>  ExtractTriggers for function INTERNAL
>  ExtractTriggers for function firebase_
>  ExtractTriggers for function __esModule
>  ExtractTriggers for function credential
>  ExtractTriggers for function cert
>  ExtractTriggers for function refreshToken
>  ExtractTriggers for function applicationDefault
>  ExtractTriggers for function SDK_VERSION
⚠  functions: Maximum call stack size exceeded
⚠  Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error.
```

When looking closely, I found out that the repetition started after the function  name `firebaseAdmin`.
And I had exported the firebase admin instance in my `index.ts`

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

//...

export const firebaseAdmin = admin;
```

Which was the root cause of it all, just removing that line, and using separate imports in all other files worked for me!

Comment: I was ripping my hair out when I got this issue... I had reduced my project to just these 2 lines and it was still failing.

Did you figure out a way to export admin (or `admin.initializeApp`)?

Comment: I don't think you need to call `admin.initializeApp` in every file that you import `admin`, I have just done it once in index.ts and it works by just importing and using the import directly in other files.